# Matching a virtual machine design with its primary programming language

Tags: jvm, language-design, vm-implementation

As background for a side project, I've been reading about different virtual machine designs, with the JVM of course getting the most press.  I've also looked at BEAM (Erlang), GHC's RTS (kind of but not quite a VM) and some of the JavaScript implementations.  Python also has a bytecode interpreter that I know exists, but have not read much about.

What I have not found is a good explanation of **why particular virtual machine design choices are made for a particular language**.  I'm particularly interested in design choices that would fit with concurrent and/or very dynamic (Ruby, JavaScript, Lisp) languages.

---

**Edit:** In response to a comment asking for specificity here is an example.  The JVM uses a stack machine rather then a register machine, which was very controversial when Java was first introduced.  It turned out that the engineers who designed the JVM had done so intending platform portability, and converting a stack machine back into a register machine was easier and more efficient then overcoming an impedance mismatch where there were too many or too few registers virtual.

Here's another example: for Haskell, the paper to look at is [Implementing lazy functional languages on stock hardware: the Spineless Tagless G-machine](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/spineless-tagless-gmachine.ps.gz).  This is very different from any other type of VM I know about.  And in point of fact GHC (the premier implementation of Haskell) does not run live, but is used as an intermediate step in compilation.  Peyton-Jones lists no less then 8 other virtual machines that didn't work.  I would like to understand why some VM's succeed where other fail.

Comment: This is a bit too broad a topic. Can you give some particular aspects of the design that you are most interested in? Or any other examples. +1 from me anyway since this could result in some interesting answers.

Comment: The Dalvik JVM uses register based architecture - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)

Comment: You should look at the documentation for Parrot http://www.parrot.org/, which was originally designed for Perl but has since been used for several other languages.  The documentation talks about VM features for dynamically typed languages vs. more static languages like Java.

Comment: SpacedMonkey - Dakvik is not a JVM and JVM `.class` files will not run on it.  Bytecode for the JVM is translated into Dalvik bytecode before being put on an Android device.

Comment: I'd be quite interested in how much, say, C# and VB.net had to do with .net IL and how much was simply based on lessons learned from Java and x86.

Comment: Isn't this better suited for Programmers?

Comment: I feel like this might be one of the coolest, totally-inappropriate-for-SO questions I've seen on SO. I'd freaking love to know what answers you get, but maybe better suited to Reddit or something. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: U can Check this http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Nicolas.Geoffray/files/pppj-08.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your question from a different tack: what is a VM?  A VM is just a specification for "interpreter" of a lower level language than the source language.  Here I'm using the black box meaning of the word "interpreter". I don't care how a VM gets implemented (as a bytecode intepereter, a JIT compiler, whatever).  When phrased that way, from a design point of view the VM isn't the interesting thing it's the low level language.

The ideal VM language will do two things.  One, it will make it easy to compile the source language into it.  And two it will also make it easy to interpret on the target platform(s) (where again the interpreter could be implemented very naively or could be some really sophisticated JIT like Hotspot or V8).

Obviously there's a tension between those two desirable properties, but they do more or less form two end points on a line through the design space of all possible VMs. (Or, perhaps some more complicated shape than a line because this isn't a flat Euclidean space, but you get the idea).  If you build your VM language far outside of that line then it won't be very useful.  That's what constrains VM design: putting it somewhere into that ideal line.

That line is also why high level VMs tend to be very language specific while low level VMs are more language agnostic but don't provide many services.  A high level VM is by its nature close to the source language which makes it far from other, different source languages.  A low level VM is by its nature close to the target platform thus close to the platform end of the ideal lines for many languages but that low level VM will also be pretty far from the "easy to compile to" end of the ideal line of most source languages.

Now, more broadly, conceptually any compiler can be seen as a series of transformations from the source language to intermediate forms that themselves can be seen as languages for VMs.  VMs for the intermediate languages may never be built, but they could be.  A compiler eventually emits the final form.  And that final form will itself be a language for a VM.  We might call that VM "JVM", "V8"...or we might call that VM "x86", "ARM", etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the techniques of deriving a VM is to just go down the compilation chain, transforming your source language into more and more low level intermediate languages. Once you spot a low level enough language suitable for a flat representation (i.e., the one which can be serialised into a sequence of "instructions"), this is pretty much your VM. And your VM interpreter or JIT compiler would just continue your transformations chain from the point you selected for a serialisation.

Some serialisation techniques are very common - e.g., using a pseudo-stack representation for expression trees (like in .NET CLR, which is not a "real" stack machine at all). Otherwise you may want to use an SSA-form for serialisation, as in LLVM, or simply a 3-address VM with an infinite number of registers (as in Dalvik). It does not really matter which way you take, since it is only a serialisation and it would be de-serialised later to carry on with your normal way of compilation.

It is a bit different story if you intend to interpret you VM code immediately instead of compiling it. There is no consensus currently in what kind of VMs are better suited for interpretation. Both stack- (or I'd dare to say, Forth-) based VMs and register-based had proven to be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found this book to be helpful.  It discusses many of the points you are asking about.  (note I'm not in any way affiliated with Amazon, nor am I promoting Amazon; just was the easiest place to link from).

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1852339691/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1852339691)

Comment: This isnt a answer u could have mentioned it as comment

Comment: Could you give me a summary of what it said on the topic?

Comment: There's an entire chapter on Implementation Techniques that makes comparison of Stack-Based vs Register machines.

Comment: Its funny you downvote an answer when you ask a broad question that has no specific answer to it.  What have you done to help yourself?  What specific problem are you having with your research?  Read a book if you want a comparison of VM designs and how they are used for different situations.

Comment: Sorry Jim its not about reading Book, its something aboout more practical answer than just suggesting a book.

Comment: Its a poor question.  The best answer that can be given, short of writing a book for an answer, is to suggest a book.  That's my opinion on the matter.